# codeigniter error after autoloading sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, header

I receive a strange error just after adding 'session' in autoload.php:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

The error is :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/farmacia/public_html/pureblack.ro/index.php:19)
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 672

This is frustrating because if i remove 'sessions' all works great. 
I have to make the modifications in order to have multilanguage support on my site. 
Thank you in advance for your help !
Cristi

Comment: Have you tried downloading the latest CI and seeing if there is just a problem with your session file?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are outputing something to the client browser and after that you are trying to send headers somewhere. You CANT output anything before headers.

Most probably the Session.php is trying to send a HEADER but you did output something with `echo` or `print` before including it.

Comment: In Codeigniter there is a file autoload.php. In the file, a line $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session'); which was initially $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); After i added 'session' i recieved that error. before that everything was OK

Comment: well, sessions are trying to send HEADER as answer mentions, please go thru your files (non view/controller/model files) that means system or config files and see if you are echoing/printing()/var_debuging something, comment it and it will work as fine as before

Comment: solved. It was the google string from the begining of php. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In the following page,

> `config/config.php`

change

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

with

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH.'ci_sessions';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with my window server.

First, remove session libraries from autoload.  Add `session_start()` top of your index.php file it will work fine.